# How does opendir work in Perl 6?

Tags: perl, raku, opendir

Can someone tell me, why the "opendir" doesn't work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

my $file = 'Dokumente/test_file';

if ( my $fh = open $file, :r ) {
    for $fh.lines -> $line {
    say $line;
    }
} else {
    say "Could not open '$file'";
}


my $dir = 'Dokumente';

my $dh = opendir $dir err die "Could not open $dir: $!";
```

Output:

> Hello, World!
>   Line 2.
>   Last line.
>
> Could not find non-existent sub &opendir
>   current instr.: '_block14' pc 29 (EVAL_1:0)
>   called from Sub '!UNIT_START' pc 1163 (src/glue/run.pir:20)
>   called from Sub 'perl6;PCT;HLLCompiler;eval' pc -1 ((unknown file):-1)
>   called from Sub 'perl6;PCT;HLLCompiler;evalfiles' pc 1303 (compilers/pct/src/PCT/HLLCompiler.pir:707)
>   called from Sub 'perl6;PCT;HLLCompiler;command_line' pc 1489 (compilers/pct/src/PCT/HLLCompiler.pir:794)
>   called from Sub 'perl6;Perl6;Compiler;main' pc -1 ((unknown file):-1)

Comment: When I write "my $dh = $dir.open();" then the error-message is:
"Method 'open' not found for invocant of class 'Perl6Str'...".

Comment: Well that's not really how it would be called. . . but at any rate, it looks like IO::Directory hasn't yet been implemented.  Serves me right for not trying before I post.  So I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opendir is just not yet implemented. Please file a bug report by sending a mail to rakudobug@perl.org.

Comment: I think if such a feature is not implemented, then it is no secret. But will there not be soon a perl6-star-release?

Answer (score 3):

Perl6 is ready now. So we can give a correct answer to this very old question.

There is no more opendir in Perl6. But thanks to many people who work on Perl 6, open a dir is now very simple.

As [perl - dir doc](https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir) says:

Opening a directory requires just to type:

```
for dir() -> $file {
    say $file;
}
```

And with a filter:

```
for dir('/path/to/dir', test => /\.jpg$/ ) -> $file {
    say $file;
}
```

So you can forget opendir, readdir, grep and other.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have Perl 6, but it looks like you are calling opendir incorrectly. This perl snippet works for me:

```
my $dh;
opendir $dh, '/home/ar' or die 'Could not open directory';
```